# Como faço para 'limpar os resultados' quando o usuário clicar novamente em SOMAR(ativando o a função calc onclick)?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Segue o código

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
      body {
        background-color: brown;
      }

      .menu button {
        font: normal 18pt Arial;
        background-color: coral;
        border-radius: 4px 4px 4px;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px;
      }

      .menu button:hover {
        background-color: rgb(252, 110, 58);
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="menu">
      <button id="som" onclick="calc()">SOMAR</button>
      <button id="sub">SUBITRAIR</button>
      <button id="divi">DIVIDIR</button>
      <button id="mut">MULTIPLICAR</button>
      <div id="div"></div>
    </nav>

    <script>
      function calc() {
        // AQUI FICAM AS VARIAVEIS
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var div1 = document.createElement("div");
        var div2 = document.createElement("div");
        var div3 = document.createElement("div");
        var div4 = document.createElement("div");
        var center = document.createElement("div");
        var inp1 = document.createElement("input", "number");
        var inp2 = document.createElement("input", "number");
        var text1 = document.createTextNode("Digite o primeiro numero: ");
        var text2 = document.createTextNode("Digite o segundo numero: ");
        var somarb = document.createElement("button");
        var container = document.querySelector("#div");

        // AQUI FICAM OS ESTILOS

        div.style.width = "90%";
        div.style.height = "520px";
        div.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        div.style.margin = "-7% 5%";
        div.style.borderRadius = "10px 10px 10px";
        div.style.boxShadow = "5px 5px 10px 4px";
        div.style.font = "normal 18pt Arial";

        div4.style.font = "normal 42pt Arial";
        div4.style.color = "#900";
        div4.style.textAlign = "center";

        somarb.innerHTML = "Calcular";
        somarb.style.backgroundColor = "#900";
        somarb.style.borderRadius = "10px 10px 10px";
        somarb.style.boxShadow = "5px 5px 10px 4px";

        center.style.margin = "10% 1%";
        center.style.font = "normal 30pt Arial";

        inp1.style.width = "400px";
        inp1.style.height = "20px";

        inp2.style.width = "400px";
        inp2.style.height = "20px";

        // AQUI FICAM OS CHILDS
        div.appendChild(center);
        center.appendChild(div2);
        center.appendChild(div1);
        center.appendChild(div3);
        center.appendChild(div4);
        div1.appendChild(text1);
        div1.appendChild(inp1);
        div2.appendChild(text2);
        div2.appendChild(inp2);
        div3.appendChild(somarb);
        container.appendChild(div);

        // AQUI FICAM AS FUNÇÕES

        somarb.onclick = function () {
          var n1 = Number(inp1.value);
          var n2 = Number(inp2.value);
          var soma = n1 + n2;

          var res = document.createTextNode(
            `A soma entre ${n1} e ${n2} é igual a ${soma}`
          );
          div4.style.margin = "10% 10%";

          div4.appendChild(res);
        };
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sei que o código não deve ta muito bom, e esse é o primeiro "projeto" que estou tentando fazer sozinho, praticando um pouco sabe..

Quando ativo a função calc, ele cria tudo de novo em baixo da div principal. eu queria que limpasse o resultado ou algo do tipo.

[image: PRINT DO QUE ESTÁ OCORRENDO]

Sei que muita coisa daria pra fazer com html ou CSS, mas tava querendo praticar JS mesmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

Acontece que o método `appendChild` sempre adiciona um novo filho no elemento. Você pode criar uma variável global chamada `oldChild`, e na hora de calcular a soma, você verifica se `oldChild` existe, e aí ele usa o método `replaceChild(newChild, oldChild)`, se não, ele usa o `appendChild(newChild)` normal.

Segue um exemplo:

```js
var oldChild;

// Segue o código normalmente

// No método do onclick:
if (oldChild) div4.replaceChild(res, oldChild);
else div4.appendChild(res);

oldChild = res;
```

Ficando inteiramente assim:

```js
somarb.onclick = function () {
  var n1 = Number(inp1.value);
  var n2 = Number(inp2.value);
  var soma = n1 + n2;

  var res = document.createTextNode(
    `A soma entre ${n1} e ${n2} é igual a ${soma}`
  );

  div4.style.margin = "10% 10%";

  if (oldChild) div4.replaceChild(res, oldChild);
  else div4.appendChild(res);

  oldChild = res;
};
```

Código completo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
      body {
        background-color: brown;
      }

      .menu button {
        font: normal 18pt Arial;
        background-color: coral;
        border-radius: 4px 4px 4px;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px;
      }

      .menu button:hover {
        background-color: rgb(252, 110, 58);
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="menu">
      <button id="som" onclick="calc()">SOMAR</button>
      <button id="sub">SUBITRAIR</button>
      <button id="divi">DIVIDIR</button>
      <button id="mut">MULTIPLICAR</button>
      <div id="div"></div>
    </nav>

    <script>
      function calc() {
        // AQUI FICAM AS VARIAVEIS
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var div1 = document.createElement("div");
        var div2 = document.createElement("div");
        var div3 = document.createElement("div");
        var div4 = document.createElement("div");
        var center = document.createElement("div");
        var inp1 = document.createElement("input", "number");
        var inp2 = document.createElement("input", "number");
        var text1 = document.createTextNode("Digite o primeiro numero: ");
        var text2 = document.createTextNode("Digite o segundo numero: ");
        var somarb = document.createElement("button");
        var container = document.querySelector("#div");
        var oldChild;

        // AQUI FICAM OS ESTILOS

        div.style.width = "90%";
        div.style.height = "520px";
        div.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        div.style.margin = "-7% 5%";
        div.style.borderRadius = "10px 10px 10px";
        div.style.boxShadow = "5px 5px 10px 4px";
        div.style.font = "normal 18pt Arial";

        div4.style.font = "normal 42pt Arial";
        div4.style.color = "#900";
        div4.style.textAlign = "center";

        somarb.innerHTML = "Calcular";
        somarb.style.backgroundColor = "#900";
        somarb.style.borderRadius = "10px 10px 10px";
        somarb.style.boxShadow = "5px 5px 10px 4px";

        center.style.margin = "10% 1%";
        center.style.font = "normal 30pt Arial";

        inp1.style.width = "400px";
        inp1.style.height = "20px";

        inp2.style.width = "400px";
        inp2.style.height = "20px";

        // AQUI FICAM OS CHILDS
        div.appendChild(center);
        center.appendChild(div2);
        center.appendChild(div1);
        center.appendChild(div3);
        center.appendChild(div4);
        div1.appendChild(text1);
        div1.appendChild(inp1);
        div2.appendChild(text2);
        div2.appendChild(inp2);
        div3.appendChild(somarb);
        container.appendChild(div);

        // AQUI FICAM AS FUNÇÕES

        somarb.onclick = function () {
          var n1 = Number(inp1.value);
          var n2 = Number(inp2.value);
          var soma = n1 + n2;

          var res = document.createTextNode(
            `A soma entre ${n1} e ${n2} é igual a ${soma}`
          );

          div4.style.margin = "10% 10%";

          if (oldChild) div4.replaceChild(res, oldChild);
          else div4.appendChild(res);

          oldChild = res;
        };
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```